# [Laravel 5.1]Custom routes display a white (blank) page

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

Im currently using XAMPP (PHP 5.6.21) on a Win 10 machine.

Im doing a migration from a site in .net to laravel. Until now i almost had no problem, most of the previous problems came from inexperience. But i can't find solutions for this error.

***routes.php***

```
//Operaciones
Route::resource('operaciones', 'OperacionesController');
//Ruta al cierre de Operaciones
Route::any('operaciones/cerrar', ['as' => 'operaciones/cerrar', function(){
dd('asdasd');
}]);
```

The resource route works fine, but the 2nd route brings me a white (blank) page

And does not matter if i put anything in the web browser

if i put

```
http://localhost:8080/mutualv0/public/operaciones/asdasdasd
```

white page, if i put

```
http://localhost:8080/mutualv0/public/operaciones/cerrar
```

withe again...

But, if y try this

```
http://localhost:8080/mutualv0/public/operaciones2
```

NotFoundHttpException

I have nothing in the logs, i installed a laravel link checker and does not trow me any errors... i just don´t know what to do...

**UPDATE**

I tried

```
php artisan route:cache
```

It brought me an error *"unable to prepare route [operaciones/cerrar] for serialization. uses closure"*

SO i change the route to this

```
Route::get('operaciones/cerrar', ['as' => 'operaciones/cerrar', 'uses' => 'OperacionesController@cerrar']);
```

And add a function to OperacionesController

```
public function cerrar()
{
    dd('hello');
}
```

I used *php artisan serve* but still having the same error... withe (blank) page...

**UPDATE 2**

The link i use is

```
<a href="{{ route('operaciones/cerrar') }}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Cerrar operaciones seleccionadas</a>
```

I tried to change the link to

```
<a href="{{ route('cerraroperaciones') }}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Cerrar operaciones seleccionadas</a>
```

And update the route to

```
Route::any('operaciones/cerrar', [
    'as' => 'cerraroperaciones', 'uses' => ' OperacionesController@cerrar'
]);
```

But it throws me a *Route [cerraroperaciones] not defined*

I also tried to do a *link_to_action*, and throws me an "action not defined" at OperacionesController@cerrar

**UPDATE 3**

Uploaded to GitHub

https://github.com/diegorosano/mutual

Comment: upload the project on git ill take a look if you can

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja updated... link -> https://github.com/diegorosano/mutual

Comment: fixed i guess, now it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to run this artisan Command

```
php artisan route:cache
```

if it does not work, check if it's a XAMPP probleme.

you need to make `Public` folder as `Rootdirectory`, (if this works for you, than thats the probleme)

1) disable XAMPP, (if you are using DB, disable php only in XAMPP)

2) open CMD & Cd to the app root directory (where you can find .env file ..etc) 
3) run the php build-in server using artisan `php artisan serve`,

this will show you a link, try if it works   `http://localhost:8000/operaciones/cerrar`

**EDIT**

Put the route above the resource route

```
    Route::any('operaciones/cerrar', [
        'as' => 'cerraroperaciones', 'uses' => ' OperacionesController@close',
    ]);
    Route::resource('operaciones', 'OperacionesController');
```

**Pics**

[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: I update the question... i used your tips but stilll not working, i change the code though

Comment: still blank... how is your enviroment?, are you using L5.2? something special?

Comment: using laragon as a devrelopment envirment, try it its better than xamp.

Comment: I upgrade from 5.1 to 5.2 and it start to show me errors, but ultimately this was the answer... put the route above the resource. Ty

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 'mulualv0' directory is the top level directory, then you should be accessing your website using:

http://localhost:8080/mutualv0/operaciones/cerrar

The top level directory is the root of your project. It includes the app, bootstrap, config, etc.. directories.

Do not include the 'public' directory in your link. Your server should be configured to serve the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hey just change your ***config/app.php*** `'env' => env('APP_ENV',
   'development'), 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),` then you can
   find the errors.
2. your second route their is no any canection with you  **OperacionesController** this route will works separate.

   `Route::any('operaciones/cerrar', ['as' => 'operaciones/cerrar', function(){
           dd('asdasd');
           }]);`
3. If you want call function ***cerrar*** from your  ***OperacionesController***  do like this

   `Route::any('operaciones/cerrar', [
       'as' => 'operaciones/cerrar', 'uses' => ' OperacionesController @cerrar'
   ]);`

but here also yu have used same route so no use of using `'as'` here

**EDIT :**

I don't know what is wrong but You directly use this it will call your function :

```
Route::any('cerraroperaciones',  OperacionesController@cerrar');
```

Comment: he is just doing a `dd('qsdsqd');` in a closure to check if it works i guess and there is a use of using as but he just should change the / with a dot

Comment: yes @AchrafKhouadja ya thr is use of using `as` if we need pretty routes we can. but he is using same thing ryt im sry if im wrong

Comment: that's a route name, it will defining form actions/ redirections etc easier so instead of doing this always `redirect('admin/whatever/product/create');` you can do this (assuming the route name is `create.product` ) `redirect()->route('create.product');`

Comment: he can use this `Route::any('operaciones/cerrar', ' OperacionesController @cerrar');` directly  not use `as` here

Comment: it still wont work i guess since ir did not work with the closure (i copy paste the code to a new l5 instalation and it works fine)

Comment: @DiegoRosano check answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2... now works every route. Ty all